# Python Percentage Change with group

Tags: python, date, average, percentage

I have a dataframe. And, I also have start dates for CODE. My dataframe contains prices from the start date to 08.06.2023.

**For each code, I can calculate the returns for 30 - 60 - 90 days ahead of the code's own start date and find the average of those returns.**

My start date is: 22.12.2022 (dd.mm.yyyy) for APPLE

My start date is: 16.11.2022 (dd.mm.yyyy) for HARLEY

My start date is: 21.10.2021 (dd.mm.yyyy) for META

| DATE | CODE | CLOSE PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08.06.2023 | APPLE | 8.5 |
| 07.06.2023 | APPLE | 7 |
| 06.06.2023 | APPLE | 9.3 |
| 05.06.2023 | APPLE | 12 |
| 04.06.2023 | APPLE | 3 |
| ...... | APPLE | ... |
| 22.12.2022 | APPLE | 25 |
| 08.06.2023 | HARLEY | 4 |
| 07.06.2023 | HARLEY | 2 |
| 06.06.2023 | HARLEY | 1 |
| 05.06.2023 | HARLEY | 5 |
| 04.06.2023 | HARLEY | 9.5 |
| ... | HARLEY | .... |
| 16.11.2022 | HARLEY | 4 |
| 08.06.2023 | META | 1.1 |
| 07.06.2023 | META | 2 |
| 06.06.2023 | META | 1 |
| 05.06.2023 | META | 15 |
| 04.06.2023 | META | 65 |
| ... | META | ... |
| 21.10.2021 | META | 5 |

My expected output;

| CODE | START DATE | AVERAGE RETURN FOR 30 DAY FROM START DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 22.12.2022 | %2 |
| HARLEY | 16.11.2022 | %4 |
| META | 21.10.2021 | %-5 |

| CODE | START DATE | AVERAGE RETURN FOR 60 DAY FROM START DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 22.12.2022 | %6 |
| HARLEY | 16.11.2022 | %3 |
| META | 21.10.2021 | %-2 |

| CODE | START DATE | AVERAGE RETURN FOR 90 DAY FROM START DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 22.12.2022 | %-1 |
| HARLEY | 16.11.2022 | %7 |
| META | 21.10.2021 | %10 |

Comment: Then... what is your question? Do you forgot something?

Comment: Can you check, My expected output?

Comment: I need daily returns for periods 30-60-90 starting from the start date and average data calculated from that daily returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your question is posed in the wrong manner, since you cannot expect that someone else do your homeworks from scratch in your place...
Here is my solution, from which you can take inspiration.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = {'DATE': ['08.06.2023', '07.06.2023', '06.06.2023', '05.06.2023', '04.06.2023', '22.12.2022', '08.06.2023', '07.06.2023', '06.06.2023', '05.06.2023', '04.06.2023', '16.11.2022', '08.06.2023', '07.06.2023','06.06.2023', '05.06.2023','04.06.2023', '21.10.2021'],
        'CODE': ['APPLE', 'APPLE', 'APPLE', 'APPLE', 'APPLE', 'APPLE', 'HARLEY', 'HARLEY', 'HARLEY', 'HARLEY', 'HARLEY', 'HARLEY', 'META', 'META', 'META', 'META', 'META', 'META'],
        'CLOSE PRICE': [8.5, 7, 9.3, 12, 3, 25, 4, 2, 1, 5, 9.5, 4, 1.1, 2, 1, 15, 65, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

start_dates = {'APPLE': datetime(2022, 12, 22),
               'HARLEY': datetime(2022, 11, 16),
               'META': datetime(2021, 10, 21)}
results = {}
for code in start_dates.keys():
    start_date = start_dates[code]
    portion_df = df.loc[df['CODE'] == code]
    if not portion_df.empty:
        prices = portion_df.loc[portion_df['DATE'] >= start_date, 'CLOSE PRICE'].values
        if len(prices) > 0:
            thirty_day_prices = prices[0:min(len(prices),30)]
            sixty_day_prices = prices[0:min(len(prices),60)]
            ninety_day_prices = prices[0:min(len(prices),90)]
            thirty_day_tot = (thirty_day_prices[-1] / thirty_day_prices[0]) - 1 if len(thirty_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan
            sixty_day_tot = (sixty_day_prices[-1] / sixty_day_prices[0]) - 1 if len(sixty_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan
            ninety_day_tot = (ninety_day_prices[-1] / ninety_day_prices[0]) - 1 if len(ninety_day_prices) > 1 else np.nan
            avg_thirty_day_return = np.nanmean(thirty_day_tot)
            avg_sixty_day_return = np.nanmean(sixty_day_tot)
            avg_ninety_day_return = np.nanmean(ninety_day_tot)
            results[code] = {'START DATE': start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'),
                             'AVERAGE GAIN FOR 30 DAY FROM START DATE': f'{avg_thirty_day_return:.0%}' if not np.isnan(avg_thirty_day_return) else 'No data',
                             'AVERAGE GAIN FOR 60 DAY FROM START DATE': f'{avg_sixty_day_return:.0%}' if not np.isnan(avg_sixty_day_return) else 'No data',
                             'AVERAGE GAIN FOR 90 DAY FROM START DATE': f'{avg_ninety_day_return:.0%}' if not np.isnan(avg_ninety_day_return) else 'No data'}
        else:
            print(f"No data available for {code} with starting date {start_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}")
    else:
        print(f"No data available for {code}")

wanted_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results, orient='index')
wanted_df.index.name = 'CODE'
```

Hoping that it is what you wanted to achieve...Bye!

Comment: Your code gives a 30-day return from the start date. From the daily returns you calculated, I want the average of the 30-60-90-day returns from the start date. You directly give the average return between day 1 and day 30. How can I fix this. I mean 1 daily return= 3 ///// 2 daily return= 5   /////////  3 daily return= 1   ///////   3 days mean of return = 9/3= 3

Comment: thirty_day_tot = (thirty_day_prices[-1] / thirty_day_prices[0]) instead of (thirty_day_prices[:-1] / thirty_day_prices[1:]) ?